# How to download Google's KML file

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, download, postman

I know that in [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps) Google says it is no longer available.

However if you just run a script to create a link like this:

```
    $timespan = [
        'year'  => '2015',
        'month'=> '0',
        'day'   => '28',
    ];
    $path = 'https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i'.$timespan['year'].'!2i'.$timespan['month'].'!3i'.$timespan['day'].'!2m3!1i'.$timespan['year'].'!2i'.$timespan['month'].'!3i'.$timespan['day'];

    echo "<a href='".$path."'>link</a>";
```

You will realise that you can actually download kml history files for specific dates which you can easily create your own data. The problem with this is that I can't do that programmatically. So, if I go and open my browser it downloads but file_get_contents for example -of course- doesn't work.

I tried to use Postman's Inceptor to re-send the request so I can mimmic it programmatically. But I couldn't succeed to send a successful request. Google responds with a 400 page.

Is there any way to mimmic browser's behavior so I can download the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request fails via `file_get_contents`since Google server requires the call to be authorized, it could be seen from the picture below (`Cookie` header contains so called *authentication tokens* such as `HSID`, `SSID` and `SID`)

[image]

**About authentication tokens**

Google uses [Security cookies](https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/types/):

> to authenticate users, prevent fraudulent use of login credentials,
>   and protect user data from unauthorized parties.

[This python example](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/pythonCode) (see `GetAuthTokens` function) demonstrates how to obtain authentication tokens.

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to perform *authorized* call by specifying security cookie:

```
$authTokens = array(
   'HSID' => '',
    'SSID' => '',
    'SID' => '',
);

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>
            'Cookie: HSID=' . $authTokens["HSID"] . '; SSID=' . $authTokens["SSID"] . '; SID=' . $authTokens["SID"]
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$content = file_get_contents($url,false, $context);
```